# Digital ocean sql connection and phpmyadmin suddenly stopped working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean

I have a Laravel app on digital ocean and it runned fine for about 4 days now.
But today when I woke up it suddenly couldn't connect to the DB.
Also when I try to login in phpmyadmin it says

> ## 2002 - Connection refused — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the config-db.php file and restarting apache, because some guy in their forums had the same problem and said that it fixed it for him, but for me it had no effect.

Other errors I see are

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

I am certain that no configuration files have been changed, it just stopped working, why that might be, and how to prevent it in the future ?

The OS is Ubutnu 18.04.13 (if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear as if your MySQL daemon is no longer running.

The hints here are that the Laravel app is not able to reach the MySQL server, and that phpMyAdmin is also unable to reach the MySQL server.

You should look in the MySQL error log for hints. You may also find hints in your syslog, depending on how your system is configured. This could give you information about why the service has stopped. You might also find information in the systemd log, which can probably best be viewed with `journalctl -u mysql -b`.

You could verify that it's actually stopped with `systemctl status mysql`, even though it's difficult for me to think of a reason why it would be running correctly but not responding to any connection attempts.

Next, you should probably start the service again with `sudo systemctl start mysql`. If it fails to start, you'll see some information about why not with information about viewing the log file, which you can copy and paste in to your question to help us further with troubleshooting.